# Is it alright to change the CSS border shorthand syntax order?

Tags: css, syntax, cross-browser, border

I recently learned that the correct syntax for defining a `border` in CSS is:

`<width> -> <style> -> <color>`.

However for years I've been doing it as:

`<width> -> <color> -> <style>`. And I have never noticed any problems, even in old IE, which is why it took so long for me to figure it out.

Is it "okay" to define borders the second way, even though it doesn't fully conform to the spec? Furthermore, could the 3 parts of this syntax be fully interchangeable across browsers?

Correct way: `border: 1px solid blue`

My way: `border: 1px blue solid`

Theoretically valid: `border: blue 1px solid` etc.

Comment: maybe sometimes others ways not accept browsers.. like safari ie.. you should use always correct way border: 1px solid blue

Comment: best way to follow w3school to avoid any browser specific issue. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border.asp

Comment: @SumitPatel the syntax in w3school is wrong or at the best not totatly true

Comment: @Ranjithv what syntax safari doesn't accept?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check [the formal syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border#Formal_syntax) you have:

```
<line-width> || <line-style> || <color>
```

and `||` ([double bar](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Value_definition_syntax#Double_bar)) means:

> Separating two or more components by a double bar, ||, means that all entities are options: at least one of them must be present, **and they may appear in any order**. Typically this is used to define the different values of a shorthand property.

So you can use any order you want and you will not face any issue with any browser since it's defined like that. If a browser doesn't accept an order then it's for sure a bug or you are considering some invalid values.

---

From [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#border-shorthand-properties) we also have the same definition including the `inherit` value

```
[ <border-width> || <border-style> || <'border-top-color'> ] | inherit
```

You have 6 different ways to define border:

```css
.box {
  padding:5px;
  margin:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" style="border:1px solid red;"></div>
<div class="box" style="border:1px red solid;"></div>
<div class="box" style="border:solid 1px red;"></div>
<div class="box" style="border:solid red 1px;"></div>
<div class="box" style="border:red 1px solid;"></div>
<div class="box" style="border:red solid 1px;"></div>
```

Comment: Note: The border will be invisible if its **style is not defined**. This is because the style defaults to none